# Which Method is Invoked Once I Open a Custom file from Mail

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller

***Short Version:***

When I exit the App (home button), `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` is set to `NO`, and open a custom file from Mail into my App, which method of a `UIViewController` is invoked?

Alternatively, How do I make my `AppDelegate` to `-performSegueWithIdentifier` of my rootViewController? Is this code safe?

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ChiesaSegue" sender:vc];
```

***More Details:***

I have got my App with storyboard **"Embedded In"** a **Navigation Controller** with two different `UIViewControllers`, let's say `FirstVC` and `SencondVC` connected together with proper Segues.  I have associated custom file extensions (let's say **.q80**) with my App by setting up my **info.plist** file, and I can see my custom file showing up with my App icon in Mail. All of this works perfectly fine.

I close the App (home button), and go to Mail, and **"Open In.."** a file, App opens up and I properly handle the incoming URL in `AppDelegate`'s

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
                                      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
                                             annotation:(id)annotation
```

Now, I want to be able to load the data of this imported URL in my `SecondVC`, however every time I **"Open In.."** a file I get old data back exactly the way I left it when I hit the home button. I don't know which method of `FirstVC` or `SecondVC` is invoked after my URL is processed in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`! I am cleaning the old data and setting up the new data in `-viewDidLoad`, and also `-viewWillAppear`. Nothing happens!

Let me know if you need code, or other details I  might have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that none of the view controller viewWillLoad/Appear/etc methods will be called when returning from the background.  If you need to some behavior in the view controllers based on things in the openURL application delegate method, then you have to trigger it explicitly.  You could use a NSNotification for this purpose.  Alternatively, if your openURL method is modifying some application model state, you could use key-value observing on your model objects.

Comment: After many tries and errors, I got 2 ways of doing this. One is via `performSegueWithIdentifier` another is using NSNotificationCenter, as you suggested. I gotta ask though, where do I have to `removeObserver:name:object`? in `dealloc`? or `viewDidUnload`? or both?

Comment: Depends where you do the addObserver.  If you do it in init then you need to undo it in dealloc.  If you do it in viewDidLoad then you need to undo it in viewDidUnload.  The key is that the add/remove calls must be balanced.